# Batch Resizing images in Photoshop through an external data sheet

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, automation, batch-processing, microsoft-excel

Is it possible to resize an image automatically, by letting Photoshop take the variable sizes from an external data (such as an Excel spreadsheet, Width and Height columns) and execute them and save them in a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. You can create a script (.js) to do the job.

[Photoshop Scripting Documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html). You want "JavaScript reference" for your version.

You will probably need to export your data as a csv or json, as getting JavaScript to read excel will be tricky.

If you're new to scripting Photoshop, check out some of the examples that come with it: they show opening files and doing operations.

NB. You might not be able to open your data file directly, in which case pasting it in (as csv, or json) into a `prompt` call would possibly suffice.